# How to activate developer mode in ODOO-14....?

Tags: odoo-14

I would like to know how to activate developer mode in Odoo 14 CE

I thought it was the same as version 13 but I can't find how to do it

Thanks in advance for your reply

Comment: Go to `Settings` and look for `Developer Tools` section in the page bottom.

Answer (score 4):

Add **debug=1** to URL params between ? and #, like this:

https://5996788-14-0.runbot52.odoo.com/web?debug=1#action=754&cids=1&menu_id=537&model=purchase.order&view_type=list

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `Settings` menu
2. Scroll down to `Developer Tools` section
3. Click `Activate the developer mode`

See this [official link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/14.0/general/developer_mode/activate.html) for other methods.